# Why is my systemd service creating write protected files?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, systemd, services

I have created a systemd service in my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop that runs a java program by calling a bash file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Script to run JMS

[Service]
ExecStart=bash /home/user/Desktop/path_to_my_file/run_java.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=run_jms.target
```

When I start this process, all the files generated by the java program **are write protected**. However, if I execute the bash file directly from the command line, the generated files **are not write protected**.

What can I do to make the systemd service not generate write protected files?

Comment: are you running the script as the same user manually as it runs as service?

Comment: When running manually I use: `bash run_java.sh`. When running the service: `sudo systemctl start runJMS`. Now I see that if I run `sudo bash run_java.sh` the files are write protected as well...

Comment: @marcos That's because the script is running as root. In the section `[Service]` add this line: `User=your_user`

Comment: @marcos they're not generally write protected, they just belong to a different user

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: Please write an answer detailing step-by-step how you resolved the issue. Then accept your answer (you will have to wait a day or so before accepting). This will prevent the question from popping up as "Unanswered" somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `User` is not specified in the `[Service]`, the output of the service might belong to another user and will therefore appear as write protected. To solve this, simply add a new line as:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=bash /home/user/Desktop/path_to_my_file/run_java.sh
User=user
```